# relational algebra queries

Tags: relational-algebra

I have these tables

```
Employee(ssn, name, sex, address, salary, bdate, dno, superssn)
fk:superssn is ssn in Employee
fk:dno is dnumber in Department

Department(dnumber, dname, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
fk:mgrssn is ssn in Employee

Dept_locations(dnumber, dlocation)
fk:dnumber is dnumber in Department

Project(pnumber, pname, plocation, dnum)
fk:dnum is dnumber in Department

Dependent(essn, dependent_name, sex, bdate, relationship)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee

Works_on(essn,pno,hours)
fk: essn is ssn in Employee; pno is pnumber in Project
```

I would like to retrieve the the birthdays of each of the children of every female employee using only the following relational algebra operations {σ, π, ∪, ρ, −, ×}.

so far I have  π bdate ( σ{sex = 'f'} Employee ) x (σ {relationship='child'} Dependent), but i don't think it is right.

Answer (score 0):

What does x stand for ?  Natural join ?  Cartesian product ?

If it's cartesian product, that cartesian product will/might have two distinct attributes named BDATE.  You need to deal with it.

If it's natural join, the BDATE attribute will be part of the join fields.  You'll need to deal with it.

Comment: × in relational algebra is always a Cartesian join.

Answer (score 0):

`π bdate (σ{sex = 'f'} Employee) x (σ{relationship='child'} Dependent)` has ambiguous `bdate`s, and will join every female employee with every child, even unrelated ones.

In any relational algebra expression, you start by projecting the attributes you care about:

```
π(ssn, sex)Employee ...something... π(essn, bdate, relationship)Dependent
```

Now you can select the tuples to join:

```
(σ{sex='f'} π(ssn, sex)Employee) ...something...
(σ{relationship='child'} π(essn, bdate, relationship)Dependent)
```

And join them:

```
(σ{sex='f'} π(ssn, sex)Employee) ×
(σ{relationship='child'} π(essn, bdate, relationship)Dependent)
```

Select only the dependents of each employee:

```
σ{ssn=essn} ((σ{sex='f'} π(ssn, sex)Employee) ×
(σ{relationship='child'} π(essn, bdate, relationship)Dependent))
```

From that, select the dependent birthdate:

```
π(bdate)(σ{ssn=essn} ((σ{sex='f'} π(ssn, sex)Employee) ×
(σ{relationship='child'} π(essn, bdate, relationship)Dependent)))
```

If you are knowledgeable about relational algebra, you may suspect that I have not done this in the most efficient way possible. You would be correct, but this does show each step separately. Optimizing this query is left as an exercise for the reader.